# Creating a diamond with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

If I run the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry( "500x500+100+100" ) 
window.attributes( "-topmost", True ) 
c = Canvas( window, width=500, height=500 )

d = 0
while d < 7:
    a = 7-d
    while a <7:
        c.create_rectangle( a * 40, d * 40, a * 40+37, d * 40+37, fill="blue", outline="" )
        a += 1
    d += 1

d = 0
while d < 7:
    a = 0
    while a <d:
        c.create_rectangle( a * 40+240, d * 40, a * 40+240+37, d * 40+37, fill="blue", outline="" )
        a += 1
    d += 1

c.pack()
mainloop()
```

It only shows the top half of the diamond:

[image]

I would like to create the bottom half as well. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by negating `y` flip the triangle upside down:

```
d = 0
while d < 7:
    a = 7-d
    while a <7:
        c.create_rectangle( a * 40, -(d * 40), a * 40+37, -(d * 40+37), fill="blue", outline="" )

        a += 1
    d += 1


d = 0
while d < 7:
    a = 0
    while a <d:
        c.create_rectangle( a * 40+240, -(d * 40), a * 40+240+37, -(d * 40+37), fill="blue", outline="" )

        a += 1
    d += 1
```

This will of course place your triangle above the top of the canvas, so next you need to shift it down until it reaches the middle, which is double the distance to the middle right now (`240*2+37`):

```
d = 0
while d < 7:
    a = 7-d
    while a <7:
        c.create_rectangle( a * 40, 240*2+37-(d * 40), a * 40+37, 240*2+37-(d * 40+37), fill="blue", outline="" )

        a += 1
    d += 1


d = 0
while d < 7:
    a = 0
    while a <d:
        c.create_rectangle( a * 40+240, 240*2+37-(d * 40), a * 40+240+37, 240*2+37-(d * 40+37), fill="blue", outline="" )

        a += 1
    d += 1
```

Add this to the bottom of your code and you'll have your diamond.

Answer (score 0):

I like how you did it, but I think it would be simpler to make an ASCII 'map' of what you want, then convert it to tkinter.  With this method, you can easily scale up the size.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry( "500x500+100+100" ) 
window.attributes( "-topmost", True ) 
c = Canvas( window, width=500, height=500 )

inputNumber = 11+2
grid = [" "*int((inputNumber-i)/2)+"X"*i for i in range(1,inputNumber,2)]
grid += grid[::-1][1:]
for y, row in enumerate(grid):
    for x, item in enumerate(row):
        if item == "X":
            c.create_rectangle( x * 40, y * 40, x * 40+37, y * 40+37, fill="blue", outline="" )

c.pack()
mainloop()
```